# Quick way of increasing MacCready's affinity?

Tags: fallout-4

I am playing the PS4 version of the game, and have completed most of the main quest. I play a lawful character, so I'd have a hard time increasing MacCready's affinity through my normal playthrough.

Is there a quick way to increase his affinity? I'm interested in his perk but don't want to hang around with him for too long. The "exploits" of stealing and quicksaving no longer work after the patches.

Note I'm not interested in general answers ("He likes when you ask for more caps", "He likes when you are rude"), but concrete steps (e.g. "This re-playable mission allows you to pass two checks that will make him like you" or "Building several of these objects will boost his affinity").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Affinity](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Affinity) Fallout 4 Wiki page, there are some tips for MacCready's love.

### Stealing

- It can be repeated by placing an item in a container owned by someone else and taking it back out, preferably in an area the Sole Survivor can close from prying eyes such as a hotel room in Goodneighbor (must wait 48 hours between each item you steal, or will not work).

This is only a "like" though, which will add 15 points to MacReady's affinity. There does not appear to be anything that MacReady "loves", which adds a good 35 points to his affinity.

### Lockpicking

- MacCready likes this, but only to locks owned by others.

While there is no exploit listed for this, it may be prudent to run around a larger city at night, picking the locks on people's homes. It's been a while since I played Fallout 4, but I'm sure most settlements have plenty of owned doors that are locked. Shops, homes, etc.

Comment: Thank you! It took me a couple of hours with stealing, but I did it: there is a room in the Third Rail with an owned trunk very near to a sofa. I placed tons of items in it at the beginning, stole one (no one would detect you), wait for 48 hours and repeat.

Comment: Also don't forget that cooldown timer for lockpicking 'likes' is 2 hours. This also works for Piper (unowned locks only) and Porter Gage (all locks)

Comment: You can save/reload to reset the timer, avoiding having to wait 48 hours in game. This helps in survival at least where waiting drains water/food.

Answer (score -1):

There is a trash can near the entrance of the third rail on the stairs inside with no one around. The trashcan is set to owned. Sit in the chair beside it, and from there you can put stuff in the trashcan and take it. But wait 48 hours in game after each item.